# Is there a difference between categorial and categorical?

Tags: differences

I am only interested in the meaning as relating to categories. I understand that there is only a ["categorical denial"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/categorical).

For example would be there be a difference between

> categor**ial** storage of data

and

> categor**ical** storage of data

?

Comment: One important difference is that [***categorial** is far less common*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=categorial%2Ccategorical&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccategorial%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccategorical%3B%2Cc0) I think mainly it's restricted to domain-specific ***linguistics*** terminology ([*categorial grammar*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorial_grammar) being an analytical approach primarily based on "functional categories").

Comment: ...I've looked, but can't come up with ***any*** other adjective that accepts both ***-ial*** and ***-ical*** suffixes. It often makes little or no difference whether ***-ic*** is extended to ***-ical*** (as ***electric / electrical, botanic / botanical***), and in circumstances like that, it often turns out that the less common version starts to acquire some "domain-specific" fine distinction of meaning.

Comment: Maybe [***central***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/central) and [***centrical***.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/centrical) Where I don't think there's *any* distinction apart from the latter being a very uncommon "hifalutin" choice.

Comment: "Is there a difference?" Of course; they're two different words. No two words are the same; there are always different connotations. Maybe you instead meant to ask what the differences are?

Answer (score 1):

From the standpoint of general usage, as reflected in the dictionaries (and I checked the OED, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/categorial), [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/category#category), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/categorial), and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/categorial)), there is no difference in meaning.

However, it is always possible that in a particular field, a word might have a much more specific technical meaning. For example, as FumbleFingers said in the comments, in linguistics, there is something called *categorial grammar*, which is normally **not** referred to as *categorical grammar*. On the other hand, in logic, there is something called a *categorial statement*, which, however, is even more often called a *categorical statement*.

In your particular case, if you search google books for *categorical storage* and *categorial storage*, you will see, first of all, that the latter is much rarer. However, based on context, it seems (to me, at least) that it means the same thing as the former.

Having said all this, I would say that, to be sure, perhaps you should pose this question to the [data science StackExchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Why data science.SE?

Comment: @Mitch Because the OP asked specifically about *categorial/-ical storage of data*. I figured this is covered either in computer science or in data science. I did a preliminary search on those two StackExchanges, and the concept seems to be appearing in the data science one.

Answer (score 1):

> categorial: of, dealing with, or involving a category

I think this is more common in US English, it's not common in British English.

> categorical: without any doubt or possibility of being changed

Is not really applicable to data - its more about being emphatic in your opinion or statement...  Its dealing with a different thing.

Comment: Merriam-Webster says about *categorical*:  "of, relating to, or constituting a category". And I excluded the meaning of *categorical* you mention in my question. I am really only interested in their difference when it comes to categories.

Comment: Americans do use the English language differently, [I may be wrong but...] I don't think it is correct use in British English for this very reason - confusion [avoidance thereof]

Comment: *Categorial* is not common in American English, either. However, for what it's worth,  the Corpus of Contemporary American English [(COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), which has 560 million words, gives 10 hits for *categorial*, while the British National Corpus [(BNC)](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/), which has 100 million words, gives 17 hits. This would suggest that, if anything, *categorial* is **much more** common in British English than in American English, by a factor of about 10!

Comment: Lies, dammed lies and statistics...?

Comment: @linguisticturn Gold nuggets are much more common than platinum ones, but the gold ones still approach the Hen's Teeth category!

Comment: *Categorical* can be used in both senses; *categorial*, which has only one sense (having to do with categories), probably tends to be used in the contexts in which it is important to avoid confusion with the other sense of *categorical* (unconditional).

Answer (score 0):

'Categorial' would be in line with philosophical use, e.g. referred to Aristotle's work, *Categories*, or categorial schemes such as Immanuel Kant's.
- Sapere Aude, Sept 13, 2023

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).